# to disassemble a data type ocaml

Tags: functional-programming, pattern-matching, ocaml

In case I have to disassemble a data type as its variable size, can I still use the "match and with, and if the answer is yes you could help me figure out how (I'm a beginner with this language), or do I or use other methods.

the type defined is this :

```
type 'state formula = 
  | And      of 'state formula list
  | Or       of 'state formula list
  | Literal  of bool
  | Variable of 'state
```

from the examples I've seen the "match and with" is used when the structure of the static type was, in my case as I do?

Comment: I have trouble understanding the question and am completely unable to parse the last sentence. Could you please rephrase? Also could you clarify what you mean by "disassemble"?

Comment: an example i have : let formula = And [ Variable "q0"; Or[ Variable "q1";Variable "q2"]; Variable "q3"]  ,  I need to parse element by element

Comment: Pattern matching if indeed the right solution, but since the data type is recursive, the function processing it needs to be recursive as well.

Comment: diassemble mean to break apart data structures

Comment: how can I do, unfortunately I am now beginning to use ocaml is so I have a bit of difficulty, I tried the "match and with" a simpler structure, and I did, but since I need this kind of structure do not know how do you help me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So here's an example which uses `match` to work with your formula type:

```
type 'state formula = | And of 'state formula list | Or of 'state formula list | Literal of bool | Variable of 'state

let rec count_vars form = match form with
| And forms 
| Or forms -> List.fold_left (+) 0 (List.map count_vars forms)
| Literal _ -> 0
| Variable _ -> 1

let formula = And [ Variable "q0"; Or[ Variable "q1";Variable "q2"]; Variable "q3"]

let vars_in_formula = count_vars formula (* 4 *)
```

Comment: for the case "And" there are not action

Comment: @Antonio: If you have a pattern, which is not followed by `->`, it "falls through" to the next case (assuming both patterns bind the same variables). In other words, the same expression is called for the `And` and the `Or` pattern.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to manipulate the type, you can use patter matching(among other things, but I find this the most elegant). It's essentially syntactical sugar for Match with.

For example:

```
let identify_formula=function
And(l) -> 0
|Or(l) -> 1
|Literal(b) -> 2
| Variable(v) -> 3;;
```

For a less trivial example of how to manipulate types:

```
type  l=Cons of int*l
    | Nil;;

let rec sum_l=function
Cons(hd,tl)->hd+ sum_l(tl)
| Nil-> 0;;

sum_l(Cons(1,Cons(2,Cons(3,Nil))));; (*r6*)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you would like a code example to adapt to your needs.

```
type 'state formula =
  | Literal of bool
  | And of 'state formula list
  | Or of 'state formula list
  | Variable of 'state

let rec eval variable_env formula =
  match formula with
    | Literal b -> b
    | Variable v -> variable_env v
    | And formulas -> List.for_all (eval variable_env) formulas
    | Or formulas -> List.exists (eval variable_env) formulas

(* same as eval, different code *)
let rec eval2 env = function
  | Literal b -> b
  | Variable v -> env v
  | And [] -> true
  | And (hd::tl) -> eval env hd && eval2 env (And tl)
  | Or [] -> false
  | Or (hd::tl) -> eval env hd || eval2 env (Or tl)
```